# Why has npm package: "fs" been replaced with a placeholder?

Tags: npm, node-modules

I have been developing my nuxt + vuejs + prisma project for a while without any package related issues. Today I open my laptop and use command "npm run dev" to run my project (as normal)

I get the following error message from the console:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors               friendly-errors 20:38:38

This dependency was not found:                        friendly-errors 20:38:38
                                                      friendly-errors 20:38:38
* fs in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
```

After searching online, trying all the fixes I came across no luck.

I decided to look into node_modules/fs/ only to find there is just:
1x package.json
1x readme

The readme:

> ## Security holding package
>
> This package name is not currently in use, but was formerly occupied
> by another package. To avoid malicious use, npm is hanging on to the
> package name, but loosely, and we'll probably give it to you if you
> want it.
>
> You may adopt this package by contacting support@npmjs.com and
> requesting the name.

In the package.json file, the "homepage" key points to here: https://github.com/npm/security-holder#readme

I am no longer sure how to fix this.

I have tried:

- re installing node modules multiple times
- upgrading/downgrading node versions

Thanks for your support!

Comment: This is because `fs` is a [built-in Node.js module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), and the `fs` entry on npm probably did contain a valid package at some point which may conflict with the built-in module, so it has since been marked as a "security holding package". I suggest you should uninstall the `fs` package, and maybe provide more context as to what could have possibly broken your installation.